# Why am I getting File not found error for ExifInterface with Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, picasso, exif

I am using Firebase to store images for my android app. The images then appear in my app in a recycler view. This all works fine, however, certain images appear sideways. Specifically those taken with a Galaxy S7.

I know that I need to get the exif information from the images but when I try I get a file not found error what can I do?

```
private int getImageOrientation(String imagePath){
        int rotate = 0;
        try {
            File imageFile = new File(imagePath);

            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    rotate = 270;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    rotate = 180;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    rotate = 90;
                    break;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rotate;
    }
```

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /https:/firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pickit-d193d.appspot.com/o/posts%2Ff12e73ad-9bc5-4485-90e5-927dbf8539a5.jpg?alt=media&token=9f92c0d7-0518-4721-a7b5-235c1fb3cc76 (No such file or directory)
```

I just need this to return how much the image is rotated but it always returns 0 since it throws a File not found expression. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`https:/firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pickit-d193d.appspot.com/o/posts%2Ff12e73ad-9bc5-4485-90e5-927dbf8539a5.jpg?alt=media&token=9f92c0d7-0518-4721-a7b5-235c1fb3cc76` is an HTTPS URL. It is not a file on the filesystem.

Download the file, then use [the AndroidX edition of `ExifInterface`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/exifinterface/media/ExifInterface) to examine it.

Or, if you will be showing these images in an `ImageView`, use an image-loading library like Glide or Picasso, which should take the EXIF orientation headers into account when displaying the images.

Comment: I am loading these images using Picasso but this does not fix the issue, I have also tried using glide. Also wouldn't downloading the file slow the app down significantly? I am using a recycler view with two images per card view. Is there any way to get the exif information directly from firebase?

Comment: @Bjorn: "I am loading these images using Picasso but this does not fix the issue, I have also tried using glide" -- then I doubt that `ExifInterface` will help you. "Also wouldn't downloading the file slow the app down significantly?" -- um, you already are downloading the images, via Glide or Picasso. "Is there any way to get the exif information directly from firebase?" -- I am not a Firebase expert, sorry.

Comment: I am trying to pass the result of this function into the .rotate() function of picasso.

Comment: @Bjorn: Last I knew, those libraries should handle EXIF headers for you. Glide certainly does -- see [this](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1173) and [this](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1120), for example.

Comment: I think that I am having a similar problem as [link](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1173) but I am not sure what could be removing the exif information.

Comment: @Bjorn: There is no requirement for a camera app to put proper EXIF information in the images that it takes. Test the image with an EXIF utility (e.g., `exiftool`) or site (e.g., http://metapicz.com) and see if it has the headers. If it doesn't, then Glide cannot rotate it and `ExifInterface` will do you no good.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer that I implemented works for me but I am not sure it will work in all cases. So when I am creating an image I set a boolean value to check if the height is more than the width. Then when I am loading the image in picasso I have:

```
Picasso.get()
                .load(imageURL_1)
                .fit()
                .rotate(post.isRotated()?0:90)
                .transform(new RoundedCornersTransformation(30,30))
                .into(imageView1);
```

Like I said this only works if the image is rotated counter clockwise 90 degrees. If there is a better fix I welcome your answers, but this is the best I can do without access to EXIF information.